# Ocultar archivos de directorios específicos de los resultados de búsqueda en navegadores

Tags: robots.txt, google-search, bing-search

estoy haciendo una aplicación donde se tiene que subir el CV del personal, el problema es que estos archivos los puedo ver en el buscador web, ¿como hago para que el navegador no rastree archivos de una carpeta?
Esto en un servidor web apache en ubuntu

Comment: Haz leído sobre el archivo .robot, creo que en esa parte especificas los archivos o carpetas que deseas que el buscador omita.

Answer (score 0):

#### Puedes usar el archivo robots.txt.

Este archivo es una de las primeras cosas que leen los robots de los buscadores (de ahí su nombre) y lo que hace es **indicar que indexar y qué no** *(no todos los buscadores del mundo te harán caso, pero seguro que Google, Bing y Yahoo! sí).*

Se trata de crear un archivo llamado robots.txt en la carpeta raíz de tu dominio, de tal forma que puedas abrirlo accediendo a `tudominio.com/robots.txt`

El contenido que debe tener es este:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /cv/
```

Siendo /cv/ el directorio que quieras ocultar. Es decir, si tus CV están en la carpeta /cv, debes indicar eso, y si están en la capeta /archivos/cv/, debes indicar /archivos/cv/.

Para ayudarte te dejo creadores de archivos robots.txt online:

- http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/generator/
- https://smallseotools.com/robots-txt-generator/

Desde este enlace puedes pegar una de las url de los CV (después de hacer el archivo) para comprobar si ha hecho efecto o no el robots.txt y también podrás encontrar mucha información acerca de su uso:

- https://sitechecker.pro/es/robots-tester/

> Recuerda que los CV tardarán en desaparecer de los resultados, y
>   puedes agilizar este proceso registrándote en los Webmaster de los
>   buscadores más populares y eliminando las URL que quieras. (Webmaster
>   Google)

https://search.google.com/search-console/about

#### Etiqueta META

Si tus CV se muestran dentro de otro archivo, (es decir, que no son accesibles de forma directa) lo mejor que puedes hacer es añadir una etiqueta **meta** en el **head** de tu código con el siguiente contenido:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```